# Randomizing obstacles for a game board

Tags: java, random

I want to place obstacles on a game board using a random number generator. 5% of the board will have a pit which is defined as "*", but the asterisk will not show unless the players lands in that spot; 10% of the board will be blocked spots indicated as "X"; the remaining 85% will be open spaces shown as "." The game board is a 10x10 array with the letter "P" at the upper left hand corner as the starting point for the player, and a "T" at the bottom right hand corner for the ending (treasure). So far I've got this, and I been watching video tutorials as well as reading to try and put this all together, but still stuck:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Adventure {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char grid[][]= new char[10][10];
        Scanner move = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Here is the current game board:");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        for(int i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {          
            for(int j=0; j<grid.length; j++) {
                grid[i][j]='.';
                grid[0][0]='P';
                grid[9][9]='T';
                System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            }
        Random obstacle = new Random();
        int obstacleNum;
        for(int k=1; k<=100; k++) {
            obstacleNum = 1+obstacle.nextInt(100);

        }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.printf("Enter your move (U/D/L/R)>");
    }
}
```

Not sure where to go after "obstacleNum = 1+obstacle.nextInt(100);"

Comment: If you were numbering each cell in the grid from 0 to 99 starting in the upper left corner and going row by row, how would you write code to do that?  If you started to do this on paper, the algorithm will more than likely come to you. I suggest that you give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the actual interactivity, here is an outline:

```
x = 0; //coordinates of player, location of P
y = 0;
```

To hide the pits, before printing, stick in and if statement:

```
if(grid[i][j]=='*') {
    System.out.println("."); //looks like ordinary land
} else {
    System.out.println(grid[i][j]);
}
```

Now have this run when it receives input (pseudo)

```
//following if for moving left
if(grid[y][x+1] isn't out of bounds and right key is pressed and grid[y][x+1]!='X') {
    grid[y][x] = '.'; //removes current position
    x++; //change location
}
//following if for moving right
if(grid[y][x-1] isn't out of bounds and left key is pressed and grid[y][x-1]!='X') {
    grid[y][x] = '.'; //removes current position
    x--; //change location
}
//following if for moving down
if(grid[y+1][x] isn't out of bounds and down key is pressed and grid[y+1][x]!='X') {
    grid[y][x] = '.'; //removes current position
    y++; //change location
}
//following if for moving up
if(grid[y-1][x] isn't out of bounds and up key is pressed and grid[y-1][x]!='X') {
    grid[y][x] = '.'; //removes current position
    y--; //change location
}
if(grid[y][x] == '*') { //when trapped in a pit
    System.out.println("You fell in a pit. Game over.");
} else {
    grid[y][x] = 'P'; //update grid
}
```

Comment: How would you scan in the movements as string variables?

Comment: What do you mean, "scan in movements?"

Comment: I apologize, what I mean to say is how do I declare each user input command (U/D/L/R) as a string variable? I tried doing this: <code> String movePlayer= "U", "D", "L", "R"; <code> but this doesn't let me initialize multiple string variables in this format.

Comment: You would use a key listener, and then when when you get a key event from it, char keyInput = myKeyEvent.getKeyChar()

Answer (score 1):

If your game board has 100 spots, then it will have 5 pits, 10 blocks, and 85 open spaces.

Choose 15 random numbers from 1 to 100; the first 5 identify the pits, and the next 10 identify the blocks.

Create a list to keep track of the 15 numbers.  Each time you choose a random number, check to see if the number is already present to the list.  If it is, discard it and choose a different random number.  Otherwise add it to the list and continue until you've chosen all 15 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a fixed amount of obstacles? You are better off putting the code in your loop that defines your the board:

```
    for(int i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {          
        for(int j=0; j<grid.length; j++) {
            int random = Math.random();
            if (random <.05){
                grid[i][j]='*';
            }else if (random < .15) {
                grid[i][j]='X'
            }else {
                grid[i][j]='.';
            }
            System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
    grid[0][0]='P';
    grid[9][9]='T';
```

Also you should put the cod just above define P and T outside the loop afterwards as it seems it only needs to be done once.

EDIT: this method will give you a representation of the game board, to cover the `*`, you can either change the print method to print them as `.` Or maintain a display grid, as well as the actual grid (eg make 2 grids)

Comment: In general this won't produce the correct number of pits or blocks because `Math.random()` is, well, random.

Comment: That's why I asked first whether he needs exactly 5% pits and 10% walls, as you said this way won't give you that exactly each time, but i prefer randomness over 'there are 5 spikes to avoid!'